# Request User Email not working in Forms.py

Tags: django, django-forms

There are a lot of Topics about this, but i can't get it to work.
After checking multiple Posts, i created an init method but i still get
email is not defined in the locations = modelform.

View:

```
form = GroupCreateForm(request.POST or None, user=request.user)
```

Forms.py:

```
class GroupCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(GroupCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean_email_address(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        if self.user and self.user.email == email:
            return email


    locations = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label='',widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), queryset=LocationData.objects.filter(email=email))        
    groupname = forms.CharField(label='', required=True ,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'rows': '1', 'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Geben Sie den Gruppen Namen an'}))


    class Meta: 
        model = GroupManagement
        fields = ['groupname', 'locations']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it like this:

Forms.py:

```
class GroupCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    locations = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label='',widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), queryset=None)        
    groupname = forms.CharField(label='', required=True ,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'rows': '1', 'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Geben Sie den Gruppen Namen an'}))

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GroupCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['locations'].queryset = LocationData.objects.all().filter(email=user.email)

    class Meta: 
        model = GroupManagement
        fields = ['groupname', 'locations']
```

Views.py:

```
form = GroupCreateForm(data=request.POST, user=request.user)


if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid():
        mulitple_choice = form.cleaned_data['locations']
        print(mulitple_choice)
```